# Prefjankie Protractor integration

Tags: protractor

I tried integrating perfjankie with my protractor test but having problems in generating the perf metrics/graphs. 
The test is successfully creating the couch database but it is not storing any perf values.

My basic API call looks like this..

```
var perfjankie = require('perfjankie');
perfjankie({
    "url": 'http://localhost:9000/index.html',
    name: "PerfPage",
    suite: "Perftests",
    time: new Date().getTime(),
    run: "1.1",
    repeat: 3,
    preScript: browser.get("http://localhost:9000/index.html"),
    selenium: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    browsers: 'chrome',
    couch: {
        server: 'http://localhost:5984',
        database: 'perfdb',
        updateSite: true,
        onlyUpdateSite: false
    },
    actions: runtest(),
});

var runtest = function() {
    return browser.elementById('my-id').then(function(ele) {
        return ele.click();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to look good to me. One way to debug this even more is to set the DEBUG environment variable to "*", something like export DEBUG="*" on linux/mac. You can also add a key called "log" in the perfjankie configurations, and set it to something like

`{

        'fatal': noop,
        'error': noop,
        'warn': noop,
        'info': noop,
        'debug': noop,
        'trace': noop
    };`

where noop is defined simply as `console.log.bind(console)`